# How to create softbody particle emitter

Tags: particles, soft-body

I've created a plane that emits soft-body object, but particles seems copying form of deforming plane object.

How to create soft-body emitter, where each particle behave as soft-body plane?

Help, please.

[image]

Comment: which "deforming plane"?

Comment: Particle system uses soft-body object as particles. And if origin soft-body is deformed - all particles are take it's form. As you can see from the screen.